# MUC room owner issue

Tags: android, iphone, ejabberd, smack, xmppframework

I Installed ejabberd and develop mobile application.

After implementing MUC functionality I face some problem below are the scenario of my issue.

In Room once user create a room, he become owner of the room and add some members into room.

But what if he get out of the room (leave room permanently)  then no owner exist in the room.

members able to chat and everything but owner of the group not available so he can not control the room and did’t get owner authority.

So, I want to know, if room owner leave the room, can room owner authority assign into some user in the room automatically?

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> So, I want to know, if room owner leave the room, can room owner authority assign into some user in the room automatically?

No, not possible automatically. The room owner, before leaving, should grant ownership to another occupant.